# How do I go about "summarizing" an array of objects like this?

Tags: javascript, sum, lodash

I have some data like this (simplified):

```
sales: [
    {
        'quantity': 20,
        'amount': 40,
        'product': {
            'id': 1
            'category': 'Chemical',
            'subcategory': 'Herbicide'
        }
    },
    {
        'quantity': 10,
        'amount': 70,
        'product': {
            'id': 1
            'category': 'Chemical',
            'subcategory': 'Herbicide'
        }
    },
    {
        'quantity': 30,
        'amount': 60,
        'product': {
            'id': 2
            'category': 'Seed',
            'subcategory': 'Corn'
        }
    }
]
```

I want to group my data by the `product.id` and sum the `quantity` and `amount` and keep the same `category` and `subcategory` (which would be the same for all same product id's)

So basically I want my data to look like this:

```
filteredSum: [
    {
        'quantity': 30,
        'amount': 110,
        'product': {
            'category': 'Chemical',
            'subcategory': 'Herbicide'
        }
    },
    {
        'quantity': 30,
        'amount': 60,
        'product': {
            'category': 'Seed',
            'subcategory': 'Corn'
        }
    }
]
```

I'm using Lodash and this is what I came up with but something tells me there is a more succinct way of doing this?

```
filteredSum: function () {
    return _(this.sales).groupBy('product.id').map(function (sales) {
        return {
            'quantity': _.sumBy(sales, function(sale) { return Number(sale.quantity); }).toFixed(2),
            'amount': _.sumBy(sales, function(sale) { return Number(sale.amount); }),
            'product': {
                'category': _.head(sales).product.category,
                'subcategory': _.head(sales).product.subcategory
            }
        }
    }).value();
}
```

Surely there is a better way?

Comment: If you can use arrow functions, `function(sale) { return Number(sale.quantity); }` becomes `sale -> Number(sale.quantity)`.  'tis a bit more succinct.

Comment: I can't use ES2015 in this project, unfortunately, as the JavaScript is not being run through any build tools.

Comment: is `quantity` and `amount` some kind of related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to have an Object with the `productId` as principal key. Then simply use a `reduce` to iterate over your array. If the `productId` of the current product already exists, simply sum its value to the previous one, otherwise add it to the object.

```js
const data = [
  {
    'quantity': 20,
    'amount': 40,
    'product': {
      'id': 1,
      'category': 'Chemical',
      'subcategory': 'Herbicide'
    }
  },
  {
    'quantity': 10,
    'amount': 70,
    'product': {
      'id': 1,
      'category': 'Chemical',
      'subcategory': 'Herbicide'
    }
  },
  {
    'quantity': 30,
    'amount': 60,
    'product': {
      'id': 2,
      'category': 'Seed',
      'subcategory': 'Corn'
    }
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[curr.product.id]) {
    acc[curr.product.id].quantity += curr.quantity;
    acc[curr.product.id].amount += curr.amount;
  } else {
    acc[curr.product.id] = curr;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

const formatedResult = Object.keys(result).map(entry => {
  return result[entry];
});

console.log(formatedResult);
```

Comment: Thanks, bud! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Question: Why does reduce return an object of objects rather than an array of objects? Any way to get it to do the latter?